# Unable to load local resource in PHP CI view page

Tags: php, html

When loading a audio src within audio tag from outside relative wamp server www path I am receiving -"unable to load local resources from server" I.e. when I am trying to load a audio file from D: drive of the host server.

I need a resolution on how to access. The D:\Recs folder from internet to play audio files using. PHP codelgniter. And HTML on view page.

Comment: <?php 

                            foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
                              echo "<tr><td>".$value['timestamp']."</td><td>".$value['mobileno']."</td><td> <audio src= '".($value['linktofile'])."'    controls>Your browser does not support the audio element.
                            </audio></td></tr>";
                             
                            }// end of foreach
                          ?>    
                        </tbody><?php } ?> 

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///S:/Recs/6/6_2018-12-02_21-29-24-343435.ogg

Answer (score 0):

That folder is not in the `DocumentRoot` of your Web Server, you could add it in a subfolder using the webserver's configuration or make a PHP script that loads the selected audio file content (with something like `file_get_contents`) and print it out. The script also needs to specify the `Content-Type` with the audio MimeType before printing the response body to allow the browser understand that is a valid audio and permit playing it.

Using the script as a proxy the usage would be like `playSound.php?audio=audiofilename.ogg` in the src of your audio tag and then, in the PHP script, internally prepend the absolute path to your audio directory (you also need to escape the filename to prevent the path transversal vulnerability like ../../privatedata.php)

Comment: Could you please elaborate as I am storing the audio files in D: drive and wamp is In C: drive  of my windows server. Could you please provide the script / algo

Comment: This is not a free code writing service, you need try to do it by yourself. Then if something doesn't work we'll help you. I've described all that you have to do with specific function names, so update your question with your tries and I'll update my response with a fix for the problems

Comment: <?php 

                            foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
                              echo "<tr><td>".$value['timestamp']."</td><td>".$value['mobileno']."</td><td> <audio src= '".($value['linktofile'])."'    controls>Your browser does not support the audio element.
                            </audio></td></tr>";
                             
                            }// end of foreach
                          ?>    
                        </tbody><?php } ?> 

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///S:/Recs/6/6_2018-12-02_21-29-24-343435.ogg

Comment: Your browser has several protections in place to prevent webpages to load directly local resources to prevent the information leak. So you need to change your `$value['linktofile']` with the link to your script for example `'playSound.php?audio=' .substr($value['linktofile'], strrpos($value['linktofile'], '/')+1);` doing so you only need to write the script to load selected file